# Quantifying Similarity of Survey Responses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, survey, likert

I have 6 survey responses with Likert scale questions and some basic demographic information. The 6 responses are pulled from the same group. They all met my selection criteria (School principals whose schools suspension rate met the criteria). Knowing the participants all met the same strict criteria, I want to analyze their survey responses to see how similar they are to each other. The survey is about their disciplinary beliefs. What is the statistical test I can run in SPSS to determine how similar (or not) the participants' survey responses (disciplinary beliefs) are? By looking at the responses I can see there is frequent agreement on many of the survey items. I need to quantify this.

Comment: This is not a test: it's a matter of defining what *you* mean by "similar."  What can you tell us about that?

Comment: Maybe percentage agreement among the survey respondents. Besides simply describing the data and each individual question and its responses, I am trying to find a way to statistically define themes that occurred. Do the 6 respondents whose schools met the cut-off criteria share a similar philosophy regarding student behavior and school discipline? Almost like variance? Do these 6 people who I selected share similar beliefs, or is it just as random as if I picked 6 random principals? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Could you explain how you would recognize and measure "agreement"?  Would agreement on a response require identical answers, or would it suffice for the answers to be "close"?  How close?  Have you considered simply doing an exploratory analysis of the data, such as a visualization that would let you see the patterns of answers?

Comment: I used a 5 point agreement scale. An identical answer would be great but I would say "strongly agree" and "agree" would also suffice. The survey is 45 questions so I am trying to find an efficient way to describe how similar the respondents were in their response. I could go on for pages describing how "5 of 6 respondents strongly agree on item 10, 6 of 6 strongly disagree with item 12" etc. If nothing else I suppose I could just state percentage of responses that have identical agreement and percentage of responses that have "close" agreement.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to identify if that percentage of identical or close agreement was significant or not, greater than expected by chance.

Comment: It's hard to conceive of any realistic chance model you could justify and use for such a comparison--especially with just six responses.

Comment: Ok. I might have 8 total but I understand that's not a lot on the scale of typical survey research. Thanks for your help, you've saved me hours of going down the rabbit hole trying to figure this out.